# Typescript using Omit on interface

Tags: typescript

I've got an array of products with type  MyType

```
export type MyType = 
 | { type: "one"; data: Product } 
 | { type: "two"; data: Product } 
 | { type: "three"; data: OtherProduct };
```

then I use a filter to build an array with
type one and two

Is it possible using Omit?
like

```
type My = Omit<MyType, '{ type: "three"; data: number }'>; (doesn't work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
type Product={}
type OtherProduct = {}

export type MyType = 
 | { type: "one"; data: Product } 
 | { type: "two"; data: Product } 
 | { type: "three"; data: OtherProduct };

 type Result = Exclude<MyType,{ type: "three" }>
```

Use `Exclude` instead of Omit. Omit works on interface properties, Exclude on union types